# UPSERT in postgres stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, update, insert, upsert

Postgres already has a way to do "upsert" but I don't like sending these long queries, I wonder if it could be implemented as a stored procedure which would accept json and perform

```
INSERT INTO ... (keys)
  VALUES (values)
  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET (setEverythingFromExcluded)
```

I know I could somehow use `json_object_keys` and `json_extract_path` or maybe directly `json_each` but my initial attempts lead nowhere so maybe somebody already did this?

Comment: Wrapping INSERT in server side procedure? It's doable in any procedural language. But your question is unclear. Do you want `SELECT upsert( 'my_table_name', 'my_json_object')`?  Please do not say "somehow", instead explain what you want (with code samples) and what you  did (with code samples) and how it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason why the UPSERT syntax and functionality was added to Postgres.  I wouldn't go into much detail, because it's described exhaustively [elsewhere](https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/), but most issues with custom upsert implementations stem from concurrency.  `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...` solves these issues and gives you, in the end, a much more concise syntax than any other solution.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he is not trying to avoid `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`, but use it for automated processing of JSON input. It's just not clear (yet) how exactly.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah, exactly - I just dont want to write it (over and over again)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter feel free to add an answer, I am not in the position to extend this one in the coming days.

Comment: Sure, if the OP edits the question to clarify and I find the time before you do.